# C++ static method returning global constant variable

Tags: c++, global-variables, constants, static-methods

Is it safe to write the following in C++:

```
// AClass.h

class AClass
{
public:
    static int get_max_size();    
};

// AClass.cpp

namespace
{
    const int MAX_SIZE = 123;
}

int AClass::get_max_size()
{
    return MAX_SIZE;
}
```

Comment: yes, what's your concern?

Comment: Undefined behaviours, leaks, whatever. Now in this example, the variable is an plain `int`, but is it safe also in general?

Comment: I see. Well, that depends on the use-case. This particular example is fine, but things change if you return a pointer to an object that's a global inside a module that gets unloaded.

Comment: Point out what you think is unsafe. This is very open-ended. How is this question likely to be found by and help future visitors?

Comment: That depends on when the function is called.